VS Code using Python - The system cannot find the path specified
For months, prior to today I was able run my python code without issue. In VS code I would use the keys ctrl+F5 and it would run. The error was ...[Errno 2] No such file or directory I found this answer and made the change.
Now it is giving me this error. (note I added some "\n" to make it more readable.)

F:\Water R\P & L\Python> f: && cd "f:\Water R\P ^& L\Python" &&
c:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
c:\Users\myname.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.4.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher 56983 --  "F:\Water R\P ^& L\Python\Data_request\replace_WQ_data.py"
The system cannot find the path specified.

In addition to the above I get a message popup window "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect". With a button to "Open launch.json". My thought was I need to have this file "launch.json" for VS code. So I created one using the guidelines of this post
I did not change anything in the launch.json file and tried to run my code again and get the same error. I also went into terminal and typed
F:\Water R\P & L\Python>python F:\Water R\P & L\Python\Data_request\replace_WQ_data.py

Below is the results

C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't find 'main' module in 'F:\Water'

I tried the relative path.
F:\Water R\P & L\Python>python Data_request\replace_WQ_data.py

This one works just fine...
Why does this not work like it has in the past months? What do I need to change in the launch.json to have the "Ctrl+F5" work like it use to?

I would remove spaces from these paths (and probably not use & in a path name either, especially with spaces around it !) - I'm not saying its bad, but you can get weird errors and these are weird errors.

Like when I first looked this I'm thinking what is the R command with a \P option, and what is the L command with a \Python option, and what happens when you & these two commands ...

This is the path name. Its a path that has been used for a while and I have not had issues until today.  To me the weird part is how it appears to place ^ prior to the & in P & L
